# fzero: Too many output arguments

Tags: matlab

To learn how to work with fzero() I tried this code:

```
function equation(x)

k=(96-x)/6;

end
```

and then:

```
x0=4;
x=fzero('equation',x0)
```

The error is:

```
??? Error using ==> fzero at 307
FZERO cannot continue because user supplied function_handle ==> equation
failed with the error below.

Too many output arguments.
```

Comment: Your equation function doesn't have any return outputs. (Not sure why the error says "too many")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fzero`is expecting a return value from your equation so (internally) it is trying to assign something to the output of that function.  If I try

```
result = equation(42);
```

I get the same error message

```
Error using equation
Too many output arguments.
```

Just change your function signature to

```
function [k] = equation(x)
```

to indicate that `k` is the output of this function.

Answer (score 0):

Try to supply the function argument as handle:

```
x = fzero(@equation,x0)
```